# Creating a separate twitter feed for all @-mentioned tweets

Tags: php, twitter

I am trying to create a feed on a site which displays all the tweets which are about me so say if some one says `@oli hello how are you?` I would like it to display separately from my twitter feed.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [statuses/mentions](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3A-statuses-mentions) method.

Answer (score 2):

5 seconds using google -> http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Libraries#PHP

Answer (score 0):

If needed, you could also use the search API, for example `http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=to%3Aoli`

This would allow you to get results without authentication, but search's API has its own limitations. See http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-Search-API-Method%3A-search